# Creating Message Box Button in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

How can I create a customized message box button in Windows Phone 8.1?

I googled it and understood that only using third party API can we create an own button for message box.

Are there any built-in methods to change the ok and cancel button in message box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the labels of the buttons by adding commands, example:
` // Create the message dialog and set its content
    var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("No internet connection has been found.");

```
// Add commands and set their callbacks; both buttons use the same callback function instead of inline event handlers
messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
    "Try again", 
    new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));
messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
    "Close", 
    new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));

// Set the command that will be invoked by default
messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;

// Set the command to be invoked when escape is pressed
messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

// Show the message dialog
await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

More information here https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/br208674?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: `MessageDialog` is used in *Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)*, I think this question is addressing `MessageBox`which is used in *Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight)*

Comment: Maybe you have right. We need author to clarify the question.